# SSAS Excel Pivot table dimensions relations

Tags: excel, ssas, business-intelligence, olap-cube

using Excel (2013/2016) to connect to SSAS OLAP Cube as pivot table.
in some SSAS databases, when i select a dimension attribute(For example Sales cubes, Item dimension, Item Description attribute) i get the list of items even without selecting any measure. 
Pivot table option "Show items with no data on rows" pivot table option is NOT checked!

While in other SSAS databases, if i do the same, the list of "items description" does not appear until i select a measure!

Also, in the first case, if i select another dimension, let us say "Warehouse", i get the list of items and underneath each item the "related" warehouses (not a repetition of all members in warehouse dimension) while in the second case, nothing appears and if in pivot table options i check the "Show items with no data on rows" i get the list of items but under each item i get the list of ALL warehouses, repeated for each item!

is there an option in cube designer i missed?! or in the data warehouse?!

No Foreign keys s defined in facts tables in both cases?

is there an option in Visual Studio Cube designer?

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I'm running into the exact same Problem :(